# Outer join of 2 tables in Bookshelf.js or Knex.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am new to Bookshelf.js and knex.  I need to write a query equivalent to this in Bookshelf/ knex

```
SELECT Inv.*, Comp.* 
FROM  Inv,   Comp
WHERE Inv.uId =2 AND Comp.cId = Inv.cId;
```

Inv Table has:

```
Id     |  primary key, integer  not null
col1   | string data
cId    | integer, foreign key references C table
uId    | integer  foreign key reference U table
```

Comp Table has:

```
cId     |  primary key, integer  not null 
col3    | string data
```

Answer (score 7):

Use knex query builder. Assuming Invs is a collection for model Inv it may look something like:

```
Invs.forge().query(function(qb) {
  qb.join('Comp', 'Comp.cId', '=', 'Inv.cId');
  qb.where('Inv.uId', 2);
}).fetch({withRelated: 'comps'}).then(...)
```

Where comps would be a relation defined in the Inv model. You could also skip bookshelf altogether and use knex directly through bookshelf.knex to form the exact query you need:

```
bookshelf.knex('Inv')
  .join('Comp', 'Comp.cId', '=', 'Inv.cId')
  .where('Inv.id', 2)
  .select()
  .then(...)
```

Comment: I needed similar complex query and it seemed like knex is inevitable. I don't know why should one use Bookshelf.js as ORM then? ORM features like association model (one-one, one-many, etc.) seems to become useless when using pure knex queries.